# CDN in react, how can I learn how to use each one of them properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cdn, jsx

Why when I use:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
```

Its works but when I use the ones from the official website:

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
```

I am using classes:

```
class App extends React.Component{
```

and ReactDOM;

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

why does it says "React" is missing ?

CDN in react, how can I learn how to use each one of them properly ?

Comment: your examples are 2 different versions of React (15.1.0 and 16).

Comment: would that be the reason? how should I use this in react 16 then?

Answer (score 3):

Both `cdn` and `unpkg` will work. Here is the working example,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>React Hello World</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/6.26.0/polyfill.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.0.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.0.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx">
      class App extends React.Component {
          render() {
              return (
                <div>
                    Hello World!
                </div>
              )
          }
      }

      ReactDOM.render(
        <App />, 
        document.getElementById("app")
      );
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: You need `polyfill` in order to work in IE11.

Comment: You need `polyfill` to work in IE11. See the updated answer that might work. Thanks.