# How to fix issue on IE when creating React JS pages

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, babeljs, compatibility, polyfills

I tried to create react application without having nodejs and package manager. It’s running fine on google and edge (edge mode) but having an issue on IE.

I tried to add polyfills via cdn but as with the current practice, import and require keywords is not available on this situation.

Comment: Are you using cdn/unpkg to load React in code? If so, I think you need to use `babel` and `polyfill` to make it work in IE 11. You can refer to the answer of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47816528/cdn-in-react-how-can-i-learn-how-to-use-each-one-of-them-properly). The sample code works well in IE 11.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.